# Typesense OR query on multiple fields

Tags: flutter, typesense

In Flutter, I'm trying to query my Typesense messages collection. I'd like to return all the messages that have message_from="abc" OR message_to="abc". Instead, in the example below, it only returns messages with message_from="abc". Could you please help? Thanks

The query below only returns

```
params = {
  'searches': [
    {
      "query_by": "message_from",
      'filter_by': 'message_from:abc',
    },
    {
      "query_by": "message_to",
      'filter_by': 'message_to:abc',
    }
  ],
};

final commonSearchParams = {
  'q': '*',
  'collection': 'messages',
  'page': page.toString(),
  'per_page': perPage.toString(),
  'group_by': 'thread',
  'sort_by': 'date:desc',
};

return typesenseClient.multiSearch
    .perform(params!, queryParams: commonSearchParams)
    .then((docs) {
  return docs["results"][0]["grouped_hits"];
});
```

Comment: Hey @jennie788, did you figure it out in the end? Many thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with comma-separated fields instead of using multi-search. I.e. `{query_by: "message_from,message_to", ...}`.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, what would the filter_by be then? 

message_from:abc, message_to:abc ??

Thanks

Comment: No need to use `filter_by`, since you can just specify `{'q': 'abc', query_by: 'message_from,message_to'}`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://typesense.org/docs/0.25.1/api/search.html#filter-parameters), filter_by OR conditions on the same field are in array notation, accros different fields with the `||` operator :

```
message_from: abc || message_to: abc
```

or, if you want exact matches:

```
message_from:= abc || message_to:= abc
```